# Accessing Session Data in ColdFusion

Tags: session, coldfusion

Here I am trying to access session data in a cold fusion page. you can verify below code Section A code was placed in first page and Section B code was placed in second page. When I am going to second page from first page by printing session data,getting an error.But I can able to access session data in first page itself. Am i missing any required tag in second page to access session data.
Can anyone please help me on it.

```
Section A
<cfapplication name="GetLeadApp"
sessionmanagement="Yes"
sessiontimeout=#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,45,0)#>
<cfset session.uid="#FORM.Username#"/>

Section B
<cfoutput>#session.uid#></cfoutput>
```

Thanks,
Swami

Comment: What is the name of the file that has `Section A`?

Comment: Home.cfm is the flle name. In this file above section A code was placed and Section B code was placed in ViewProfile.cfm. I am redirecting to it from Home.cfm through URL.

Comment: It must be `application.cfm` (traditional ColdFusion applications) or `application.cfc` (modern ColdFusion applications).

Comment: `Although Windows is case-insensitive, you must always start the Application.cfc filename with an uppercase A.` https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/application-variables.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my limited experience, the filename must be either application.cfc (for universal settings) or application.cfm (for directory-specific settings).

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/designing-and-optimizing-a-coldfusion-application/using-an-application-cfm-page.html

So if you're in directory "adir/bdir" and you want to access session variables from directory "adir", you can create a file named "adir/application.cfm" with code from your "Section A", then create another file named "adir/bdir/[name of file].cfm" and put your "Section B".  This should enable access to "Section A" session variable from "Section B".

Comment: Ben, Thank you so much for your reply. I have modified the file name as application.cfm and it's working fine now.

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it swamy!

Comment: Consider using `application.cfc`. It has a whole lot more control over the lifecycle of your application.